# Parcelable Array List does not working

Tags: android, parcelable

I have a custom object and an Array List, I get a null exception when i try to retrieve a parcelable Array List. The code from the custom object:

```
public class Patient implements Parcelable {

private String fullName;
private String id; // this is the Key of the Table Patient
private String address;
private int age;
private String telephone;
private String Doctor;
private String  lastVisit;
private String healthStatus;

//constructor
public Patient(String fullName, String id, String address, int age, String telephone, String doctor, String lastVisit, String healthStatus) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.id = id;
    this.address = address;
    this.age = age;
    this.telephone = telephone;
    Doctor = doctor;
    this.lastVisit = lastVisit;
    this.healthStatus = healthStatus;
}

//Key
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public String getTelephone() {
    return telephone;
}

public String getDoctor() {
    return Doctor;
}

public String getFullName() {

    return fullName;
}

public String getLastVisit() {
    return lastVisit;
}

public String getHealthStatus() {
    return healthStatus;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(age);
    dest.writeString(fullName);
    dest.writeString(address);
    dest.writeString(id);
    dest.writeString(telephone);
    dest.writeString(Doctor);
    dest.writeString(String.valueOf(lastVisit));
    dest.writeString(healthStatus);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Patient> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Patient>() {
    public Patient createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Patient(in);
    }

    public Patient[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Patient  [size];
    }

};

private Patient(Parcel in) {
    age = in.readInt();
    fullName = in.readString();
    address = in.readString();
    id = in.readString();
    telephone = in.readString();
    Doctor = in.readString();
    fullName = in.readString();
    healthStatus = in.readString();
    lastVisit =  in.readString();
}

}
```

The part of code from the first Activity:

```
 if (user != null) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(logIn.this, MainActivity.class);
       if(mPatientList != null){
            for(int i = 0 ; i < mPatientList.size(); i ++){
               if(stUserName.equals(mPatientList.get(i).getDoctor())){
                    UserList.add(mPatientList.get(i));
               }
            }
       Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
       bundle.putParcelableArrayList("patientList", UserList);
       intent.putExtras(bundle);
       startActivity(intent);
       finish();
 }
```

and the part of code from the next Activity where I try to retrieve the list :

```
if(savedInstanceState != null) {
    patientList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("patientList");
}
```

For some reason the List from the Next Activity is null and i get an Exception when trying to use it.

I follow the documentation and i cannot figure out where is the wrong part. Also the lists in the First activity are full with data.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You are putting the list in the intent but you are trying to retrieve it from `savedInstanceState` in the second activity.  You need to retrieve the list from the intent.

```
patientList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayList("patientList"); // May require a cast if you partient list is a specific type
```

Comment: Ok thanks , now i get this: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7864421 at offset 360

Comment: you are reading `fullName` twice when unmarshalling.  Check this line `fullName = in.readString();`  its there twice.

Comment: Yes , I know I fount it before , thanks for the help!